# how to take 1 panel from the results from ggplot predict

Tags: r, ggplot2, predict

I used a multivariable and univariable regression model to explore the relationship between variables.

```
model<- lrm(mortality ~value_day0 + value_day5, dataframe, x=TRUE, y=TRUE)
uni_model<-lrm(mortality ~value_day0, dataframe, x=TRUE, y=TRUE)
```

Then to visualise:

```
plot_model<- ggplot(Predict(model, fun=plogis), sepdiscrete="vertical", ylab="risk of mortality")
plot_uni_model<-ggplot(Predict(uni_model, fun=plogis),
                       ylab= "Risk of mortality", ylim=c(0,1), sepdiscrete="vertical")
```

This gives me 2 graphs: graph 1 with 2 subplots/ subpanels, 1 for the day 0 value and 1 for the day 5 value and another graph (graph 2) with just 1 panel. I would like to show the results in a different way: from graph 1 I want to combine 1 subpanel (day 0) with graph 2.
Expected results:

- graph with 2 panels: day 0 from the multivariate analysis and day 0 from the univariate analysis
- graph with 1 panel: day 5 from the multivariate analysis

Some sample data

```
dataframe<-data.frame(mortality=rep(c(0,1), each=500), value_day0=sample(1:5, 1000, replace=TRUE), value_day5=sample(1:5, 1000, replace=TRUE))

ddist <- datadist(value_day0, value_day5, mortality)
options(datadist='ddist')
detach(dataframe)
```

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some hours I found a possible solution, just in case anyone ever needs it:

remove the rows and column that create the graph for day 0, so only the value 0 graph is created
`model$data<-model$data[-c(501:1000), -c(2)]`